# Reversing Property Name and Value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, properties

In shell, is there a way (preferably with a one line command) that would allow me to reverse the property name and value in a property file? I figure I could do this with Java or another programming language, but would like something I could easily use as part of a script without dependencies to other languages.

Input file (`input.properties`):

```
var1=foo
var2=bar
var3=hello world
```

Output file (`output.properties`):

```
foo=var1
bar=var2
hello world=var3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="="} {print $2,$1}' input.properties >output.properties
```

Output to output.properties:

```
foo=var1
bar=var2
hello world=var3
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/?ref=binfind.com/web)

Comment: That was quick. I'll try it out and will accept if it works :) Might want to change `file` to `input.properties` and then also add something like a `> output.properties`.

Comment: Used this to do: `awk -F= '{print $2"="$1}' input.properties > output.properties` which aligns with the names in the question.

Comment: Need to wait 9 more minutes to accept, will accept once the time limit is up.

Answer (score 2):

This is a “pure bash“ solution, which succeeds invoking no external program:

```
while IFS== read k v; do echo $v=$k; done  <input.properties >output.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/(.*)=(.*)/\2=\1/' input.properties > output.properties
```